# The tag system for the question isn't working as the exchange change only occurs on the last button

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

Button Method

```swift
@objc func buttonFuction(){
        
        let stacView = UIStackView()
        stacView.spacing = 12
        stacView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stacView.axis = .horizontal
        stacView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view!.addSubview(stacView)
        
        buttonNames = ["One","Two","Three","Four"]
        
        for i in 0..<buttonNames.count{
            
            index+=i
            button = Button()
            button.setTitle(buttonNames[i], for: .normal)
            stacView.addArrangedSubview(button)
            buttons.append(button)
            button.tag = index
            button.addTarget(self, action: selectors[i], for: .touchUpInside)
            button.addTarget(self, action: selectorsColor[i], for: .touchDown)
        }
    
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([stacView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view!.centerXAnchor),stacView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view!.centerYAnchor),stacView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350),stacView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:70)])
        
}
```

Button handler methods

```
@objc func colorButton1(){
    
    if button.tag == 0 {
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1123025946, green: 1, blue: 0.03079073749, alpha: 1)
    }
    
    else {
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7974829231, green: 0.09321228972, blue: 0.09321228972, alpha: 1)
    }
    
}

@objc func colorButton2(){
    
    if button.tag == 1 {
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.07117979832, green: 0.8973241221, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    }
 
    else {
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7312681945, green: 0.1133923198, blue: 0.06002510149, alpha: 1)
    }
    
}

@objc func colorButton3(){
    
    if button.tag == 2 {
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1123025946, green: 1, blue: 0.03079073749, alpha: 1)
    }
    
    else {
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6805654408, green: 0.1003367522, blue: 0.09689761347, alpha: 1)
    }
    
}

@objc func colorButton4(){
    
    if button.tag == 3 {
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1123025946, green: 1, blue: 0.03079073749, alpha: 1)
    }
    
    else {
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7620294414, green: 0.05229266211, blue: 0.09308676813, alpha: 1)
    }
```

}

Every time I press the button it keeps changing colour to the last button, even after tagging each button, the colour change only occurs in the last button and not sure how to change the code to allow the colour change to happen on other button when pressed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is this question tagged SwiftUI? Also, what is Button? (As in `Button()`.)

Comment: Apologies yeah programmatically created a button object

Comment: It looks like the reference type trap, the same variable `button` is added 4 times to `buttons` and contains 4 times the last created button. Put `let` in front of `button = Button()`

Comment: Yes but a button object is a UIButton, so what exactly is a Button?

Comment: I tried adding let and the colour doesn't change at all.

Comment: I didn't use interface to create the button I coded the basic in a class and created a object to represent the class through the object.

Comment: You need four *button* variables, the single variable `button` points always to the same object. Or get the appropriate button by index from the `buttons` array.

Comment: How do I do that ? and get appropriate button by index to state which button is being pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the `buttons` array contains 4 items which all point – due to reference semantics – to the same instance, the lastly added `Button` instance. So does also the `button` property.

You need something like this, it creates four **different** `Button` instances and uses **one** action method, I don't know what the second selector does so I commented it out.

The logic: The `sender` parameter is the just tapped button, first set all background colors **except** the current button to their appropriate red colors, then set the background color of the current button to the green color. The references to the buttons are taken from the `buttons` array.

```
for i in 0..<buttonNames.count{
    let button = Button()
    button.setTitle(buttonNames[i], for: .normal)
    stacView.addArrangedSubview(button)
    buttons.append(button)
    button.tag = i
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(colorButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    // button.addTarget(self, action: selectorsColor[i], for: .touchDown)
}
```

---

```
@objc func colorButton(_ sender : Button) {
    let offColors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.7974829231, green: 0.09321228972, blue: 0.09321228972, alpha: 1),
                     #colorLiteral(red: 0.7312681945, green: 0.1133923198, blue: 0.06002510149, alpha: 1),
                     #colorLiteral(red: 0.6805654408, green: 0.1003367522, blue: 0.09689761347, alpha: 1),
                     #colorLiteral(red: 0.7620294414, green: 0.05229266211, blue: 0.09308676813, alpha: 1)]
    for i in 0..<4 where i != sender.tag {
        buttons[i].backgroundColor = offColors[i]
    }
    switch sender.tag {
        case 0: sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1123025946, green: 1, blue: 0.03079073749, alpha: 1)
        case 1: sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.07117979832, green: 0.8973241221, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        case 2: sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1123025946, green: 1, blue: 0.03079073749, alpha: 1)
        case 3: sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1123025946, green: 1, blue: 0.03079073749, alpha: 1)
        default: break
    }
}
```